# Retornar en una ListView informacion de 2 modelos filtrado por el usuario autenticado

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, listview

Quisiera saber como puedo retornar la información de un usuario autenticado de 2 modelos en una `ListView`

Archivo `models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ModelOne1(models.Model):
    VALUE1 = 'value1'
    VALUE2 = 'value2'
    DAYS = (
        (VALUE1, 'value1'),
        (VALUE2, 'value2'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    days = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=DAYS, default=VALUE1)

    def is_upperclass(self):
        return self.days in (self.VALUE1, self.VALUE2)


class ModelTwo2(models.Model):
    VALUE1 = 'value1'
    VALUE2 = 'value2'
    DAYS = (
        (VALUE1, 'value1'),
        (VALUE2, 'value2'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    days = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=DAYS, default=VALUE1)

    def is_upperclass(self):
        return self.days in (self.VALUE1, self.VALUE2)
```

Cree este otro modelo en este mismo archivo pasandole como valores los otros 2 modelos.

```
class Allmodels(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(ModelOne1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    model2 = models.ForeignKey(ModelTwo2, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Archivo `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from .models import ModelOne1, ModelTwo2
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class FormOfModel1(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model  = ModelOne1
        fields = ['days']
        widgets = {
            'user': forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all()),
            'days': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'x'}),
        }


class FormOfModel2(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
          model  = ModelTwo2
          fields = ['days']
          widgets = {
              'user': forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all()),
              'days': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'x'}),
          }
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
class AllView(ListView):
     model = Allmodels
     template_name = 'x/allview_list.html'

     def get_queryset(self):
         return Allmodels.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Y finalmente esta es la vista que quiero devolver, pero no se como filtrar la información de los 2 modelos para que lo pueda ver el usuario autenticado.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres hacer es usar tu `Allmodels` para filtrar el usuario logueado en `ModelOne1` y `ModelOne2` entonces puedes hacer esto en tu vista:

```
class AllView(ListView):
     model = Allmodels
     template_name = 'x/allview_list.html'

     def get_queryset(self):
         return Allmodels.objects.filter(
             model1__user=self.request.user,
             model2__user=self.request.user
         )
```

Tanto el campo `model1` como `model2` tienen relación hacia el usuario. Con esos lookups puedes sacar la información del usuario para cada uno.

Para iterar en el template usas el `object_list` que te da el `ListView`:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    {{object.model1.user}}
    {{object.model1.days}}
    {{object.model2.user}}
    {{object.model2.days}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Y en la template_list, como se podría hacer el ciclo for? para mostrar la info

Comment: @YamamotoAY actualicé mi respuesta. Espero que te sirva.